# Mongo Giving 'duplicate key error' on non-unique fields

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting a MongoDB error when trying to insert a subdocument.  The subdocs already have unique _ids, but an error is being thrown for a different, non-unique field that I don't want unique.

The error in Angular is: "Assets.serial already exist".  **How can I make this field contain duplicate values, and what is causing the model to assume it should be unique?**

Here is my Mongoose model:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var AssetUrlSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: false,
    default: '',
    trim: true
  },
  url: {
    type: String,
    unique: false,
    default: 'http://placehold.it/75x75',
    trim: true
  },
}),

AssetSchema = new Schema({
  serial: {
    type: Number,
    unique: false
  },
  urls: {
    type: [AssetUrlSchema],
    unique: false,
    default: [
      { name: '', url: 'http://placehold.it/75x75' },
      { name: '', url: 'http://placehold.it/75x75' }
    ]
  }
}),

/**
 * Item Schema
 */
ItemSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please enter name',
        trim: true
    },

  assets: {
    type: [AssetSchema],
    default: [],
    unique: false
  },

  property: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    zd: 'Please select a property',
    ref: 'Property'
  },

    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },

    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});

mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

And here is my 'save' method:

```
function(){
      var i = 0, assets = [];

      for (;i < 24;i++) {
        assets.push({
          serial: 1000+i,
          urls: {
            name: 'Asset Name ' + i,
            url: 'http://placehold.it/75x75?'
          }
        });
      }

      item = new Items ({
        name: 'FPO',
        property: newPropId,
        assets: assets
      });

      return item.$save(
        function(response){ return response; },
        function(errorResponse) {
          $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        }
      );
    }
```

The first time I insert a document, it works fine.  Any subsequent time, it fails with a 400 because the assets.serial field is not unique.  However, I am specifically marking that field as unique:false.

The error in the mode console is:

```
{ [MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: mean-dev.items.$assets.serial_1  dup key: { : 1000 }]
name: 'MongoError',
code: 11000,
err: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: mean-dev.items.$assets.serial_1  dup key: { : 1000 }' }
POST /api/items 400 14.347 ms - 41
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Mongoose doesn't remove existing indexes so you'll need to explicitly drop the index to get rid of it.  In the shell:

```
> db.items.dropIndex('assets.serial_1')
```

This will happen if you initially define that field `unique: true` but then later remove that from the schema definition or change it to `unique: false`.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but what is making the field an index?  It should never be unique.

Comment: @BrandonFitzpatrick It must have been created as a unique index at some point in the past. It won't be after you drop it and let Mongoose recreate it using the current schema definition.

Comment: Not sure how it happened, but dropping the index fixes it.  Thanks!

Comment: Good God bless you son! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MongoAtlas, you can go to the collection -> click 'indexes' -> on the index you want to delete, click 'drop index'

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a dev/prototype mode, simply deleting the actual collection (after changing the unique:true to false for instance), will reset everything and mongoose will allow your duplicates.