# Duplicate key error when creating record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This error is really confusing. I can create record once but second time no matter what, error would appear:

```
E11000 duplicate key error index: test_db.students.$code_1 dup key: { : null }
```

This is my schema:

```
var Schema  = {
    "stuCode" : String,
    "firstName" : Boolean,
    "lastName" : Boolean,
    "email" : String
};
```

Before I had `stuCode` as `code` and `_code`and it was required it's unique. That could maybe cause a problem.

I've tried to delete all the data from that collection, remove collection in `mongoose.connection.on('open', function(){ });` but the problem is still there. I can only save first record and second one is impossible to save.

What would be the solution for this problem?

Comment: The same `stuCode` of second document as the first document?

Comment: @zangw - you mean...... . .a duplicate key?  )

Comment: @MartinJames, yes, I mean the duplicate `stuCode`...

Comment: @zangw, second `stuCode` is not the same as first one. It's generated randomly and I've printed it in console to double check.

Comment: Only the `stuCode` is required unique in the Schema?

Comment: May suggest you just remove unique index from `stuCode`, then insert those two documents again?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774947/mongo-giving-duplicate-key-error-on-non-unique-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before I had stuCode as code and _codeand it was required it's unique.
>   That could maybe cause a problem.

Yes that old index on `code` is probably still there, can't you drop it ?

Comment: Thank you. It works. Just one note for other people who will look for this problem. This is how to remove indexes: `Student.collection.dropAllIndexes(function (err, results) { ... });`