# MongoDB - Trying to save multiple documents results in duplicate key error for a schema's ObjectId despite no unique key set

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got these two schemas:

```
const Account = mongoose.model('Account', new Schema({
  name: {type: String, default: '', required: true},
  email: {type: String, default: '', unique: true, required: true},
  hashed_password: {type: String, default: '', select: false, required: true},
  role: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Role', required: true},
  organisations: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Organisation'}],
  updatedAt: {type: Date, default: null},
  createdAt: {type: Date, default: new Date(), required: true}
}));

const Organisation = mongoose.model('Organisation', new Schema({
  name: {type: String, default: '', required: true, unique: true},
  email: {type: String, default: '', required: true},
  accounts: {type: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account'}], required: true, default: []},
  declinedInvites: {type: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account'}], default: []},  
  admins: {type: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account'}], required: true, default: []},
  updatedAt: {type: Date, default: null},
  updatedBy: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account', default: null},
  createdAt: {type: Date, default: new Date(), required: true},
  createdBy: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account', default: null, required: true}
}));
```

If I save one `Organisation` to the database, and then try to save another using this route:

```
router.post('/organisations', auth.verifyToken, (req, res, next) => {

  const creator = req.decoded._doc._id;

  const organisation = new Organisation({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    accounts: [creator],
    declinedInvites: [],
    admins: [creator],
    createdBy: creator
  });

  organisation.save((err, organisation) => {

    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
  });
});
```

It throws an error like:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: docs.organisations index: accounts_1 dup key: { : ObjectId('5a0d89e89141e410a9617746') }
```

The same goes for the empty array `declinedInvites`, it will throw an error saying the same thing but:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: docs.organisations index: declinedInvites_1 dup key: { : undefined }
```

I don't understand what is happening here, why does it throw duplicate key error when I have no `unique` key set in the schema(s)?

Comment: Hi, I think this shoudl sholve your problem [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774947/mongo-giving-duplicate-key-error-on-non-unique-fields)

Comment: Can you show `docs.organisations` indexes?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT That was it, I didn't know it worked like that.. That's really annoying. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz To be fair I didn't knew it as well before to look at it, seeing your interesting question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Grégory NEUT pointed out, if you go from having a `unique` key set in your schema and then remove it, the index will still be there, treating it as if you still have the `unique` key set.

The solution to this is to simply remove the index(es) with this command:

```
db.items.dropIndex('some-index-path')
```

Or in my case I ran my custom script for refreshing the database, which solved it for all indexes where this might have been a problem, rather than having to run it for each index.