# Express.js duplicate key error, unique not mentioned in schema

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to save a note in my mongodb using express.js .

Here is the schema I am using.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const NotesSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user",
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  tag: {
    type: String,
    default: "General",
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("notes", NotesSchema);
```

And I am trying to save the note in this way

```
const { title, description, tag } = req.body;
      const note = new Notes({
        title,
        description,
        tag,
        user: req.user.id,
      });
      note.save();
```

But I am getting the error:

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.notes index: description_1 dup key: { description: "My Desc 4" }
```

I don't want the description to be unique. Nither it is mentioned to be unique in the schema.
What is the reason for it and how can it be solved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774947/mongo-giving-duplicate-key-error-on-non-unique-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use `{unique: true}` before?
If you did you need to drop it manually. Use mongo shell or Compass for this purpose.